# Сложные манипуляции над запросом

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос, ssrs

Имеется фрагмент SSRS запроса для Dynamic CRM 2011. На данный момент выводятся все объекты нужного периода. Каким образом можно выполнить дополнительную фильтрацию и, например, вернуть возвращаемые значения для разных групп столбцов?

```
/*DECLARE @StartDate datetime
SET @StartDate = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
SET @EndDate = '2019-05-21'*/

;WITH CTE_incident AS
(
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, i.createdon, 112), 4) AS yyyy, 
RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, i.createdon, 112), 6), 2) AS mm,
ISNULL(ISNULL(ed.new_accountname, i.new_editionname), i.new_sourcename) AS edition,
ISNULL(e.new_directionname, i.new_directionname) AS direction,
i.new_typename AS itype
FROM Filterednew_incident i
LEFT JOIN Filterednew_estate e ON i.new_estate = e.new_estateid
LEFT JOIN Filterednew_edition ed ON i.new_edition = ed.new_editionid
WHERE CAST(i.createdon AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND i.new_incidentchannel IN (@incidentchannel)
AND (e.new_directionname IS NOT NULL OR i.new_directionname IS NOT NULL)
AND (ISNULL(ISNULL(ed.new_accountname, i.new_editionname), '') <> 'Сайт Клон' OR i.new_thematic = 1)
)

SELECT yyyy AS 'Год', mm AS 'Месяц', edition AS 'Рекламный ресурс', direction AS 'Сегмент рынка', COUNT (*) AS 'Кол-во', itype AS 'Тип обращения'
FROM CTE_incident
GROUP BY yyyy, mm, edition, direction, itype
```

Comment: Варианты (неисчерпывающий список): 1) Модифицировать основной запрос; 2) Превратить основной запрос во второй CTE, и написать новый основной с требуемой обработкой; 3) Преобразовать запрос в представление и на его основе написать новый запрос с требуемой обработкой.

Comment: Со вторым CTE никак не выходит: имя уникально, UNION соединяет два SELECT'а, но все равно ошибки. А третий пункт интересен, не могли бы Вы привести пример?

Comment: Что тут требует примера - не понял... тупо добавляете в голову своему запросу `CREATE VIEW myview AS`, и в новом запросе столь же тупо `SELECT ... FROM myview ...`.